# How to make an HTTPS Get/Post request?

Tags: c++, qt, blackberry, qml, blackberry-10

I'm developing a BlackBerry 10 mobile application using the Momentics IDE 2.1.2 (native SDK).

I need to access a https page that uses TLS v1.2 encryption and do not allow SSL v3. How can I access that using QNetworkRequest, QNetworkAccessManager ?

Most successful attempt was to set TLS default configuration to QNetworkRequest :

```
QNetworkAccessManager* netManager;

QNetworkRequest request;

QSslConfiguration config(QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration());
config.setProtocol(QSsl::TlsV1SslV3);

request.setSslConfiguration(config);

request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", userAgent.toUtf8()); // userAgent -> QString type
request.setUrl(url); // url -> QUrl type

netManager->get(request);
```

For **http** it work perfectly, but when it comes to **https** it returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I use this method.  You can try it to see if it works for your case.

```
QSslConfiguration sslconf;
sslconf.setPeerVerifyMode(QSslSocket::VerifyNone);
request.setSslConfiguration(sslconf);
```

Comment: Why don't you want to verify the certificate?